# Local AWS lambda: Can't invoke function when using network_mode: host

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to test an AWS lambda function locally, when I invoke the function, I get an error,

```
curl "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{"name": "Foo"}'

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9000 after 4 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

I was previously able to invoke this function, as just a hello world function However, I now need to connect to a local Mongo instance running, therefore I need to add `--network host` option so that I can connect to a local Mongo db instance.

My `compose.yaml` file consists of,

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  lambda:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 9000:8080
    environment:
      - AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT=60
      - MONGO_DB_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/
    network_mode: host
```

If I remove `network_mode: host`; the function will invoke and will return an error trying to connect to the Mongo instance.